# Определить часовой пояс пользователя Telegram

Tags: php, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем привет. 
Пишу напоминалку, нужно определять часовой пояс пользователя Telegram.

Пользователь получает сообщение:
- Введите свое время, например 12:30

Пользователь вводит например 15:43 а на сервере время 19:43.
Как можно определить часовой пояс пользователя?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Comment: Зачем мне js? Я же русским языком написал что пользователь вводит в сообщении время, это бот для телеграмм.

Comment: Куда пользователь вводит время? Прям в PHP скрипт руками забивает?

Comment: В диалог, а в скрипте получаю регулярками if (preg_match('/^(\d{1,2}):(\d{1,2})/i', $body, $times))

Comment: Продолжаем допрос... В какой диалог? Где он у пользователя отображается? Так-то телепатия - не моя сильная сторона, так что потрудитесь все-же более подробно рассказать, как устроено ваше приложение

Comment: Есть такой мессенджер как телеграм, что-то типа Viber,Whatsapp,Skype. Пользователь в диалоге пишет пишет время, например 15:45 и мой скрипт регулярками получает это значение. Дальше по логике скрипт должен узнать часовой пояс сравнив его время и на сервере и занести в БД.

Comment: Определить часовой пояс по времени нельзя, потому что одному и тому же времени может соответствовать несколько часовых поясов (например, +03:00 помимо московского часового пояса имеют ещё полсотни других часовых поясов в Европе, Азии и Африке)

Comment: Ну а как быть тогда? Js не смогу использовать, заставлять писать часовой пояс тоже не вариант так как многие начинают тупить, гугл сервис что ниже посоветовали не понимает города введенные на кириллице.

Answer (score 2):

[ответ на английском stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871426/telegram-bot-get-user-timezone)

> It's imposible by standard Bot API.
>
> You can ask user for location, and next, from this location calculate
>   timezone for user.

С помощью стандартного API это невозможно.

Вы можете сперва спросить пользователя о его местоположении и, исходя из ответа, определить его часовой пояс.

Comment: Как вариант, но как тогда определить по городу его временную зону, может api есть каких то сервисов либо же средствами php. Можно было бы в лоб просить написать часовой пояс +3 но как показала практика многие начинают тупить. Поэтому нужно определить либо если пользователь ввел время или по городу. Создавать массив в формате "Москва" => "+3" тоже не гуд, городов то не мало

Comment: тут вам не обойтись без внешних сервисов. Например можно использовать гугловские сервисы https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

Comment: они только по долготе и широте, по названию города я не нашел в документации чтобы было. Да и опять же нужно чтобы город вводили на русском, а их api вряд ли поймет город введенный на кирилице

Comment: Ну там же рядом совсем и API геокодинга есть https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start